# Twitter trending topics for a country without WOEID

Tags: python, twitter

I need to do some text mining of trending topics from El Salvador, but this country does not have a WOEID active code.

Any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using `API.trends_closest(lat, long)`. I'm not sure this will work.